# Hibernate exception - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate

In one self join class I have two parents (setter and checker) and each parent has a one to many relationship with the module class. I would like to get the id of each type of parent and along with the id also get the children(modules) associated with that id. So I've been implementing it like this:

Staff

```
  public class Staff implements Serializable, 
  @Id
  @Column(name = "staff_id")
  private String staffId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
  private Staff checker;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Staff> setters = new HashSet<Staff>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="setter")
  private Set<Module> sModule = new HashSet<Module>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="checker")
  private Set<Module> cModule = new HashSet<Module>(); 

 //getters and setters}
```

Module

```
  public class Module implements Serializable{

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
 @JoinColumn(name="staff_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private Staff setter;

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
 @JoinColumn(name="checker_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private Staff checker; 

 //getters and setters }
```

DAO code

```
    @Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Staff getWithModules(String staffId){

//Retrieve Staff
    Criteria crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Staff.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("staffId", staffId));
    Staff staff = get(crit);

    //Retrieve the modules for the staff
    crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("setter.staffId", staffId));
    crit.add(Restrictions.isNull("checkerId"));
    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("moduleId"));
    Set<Module> sModule = new LinkedHashSet<Module>(crit.list());
    staff.setsModule(sModule);  
    return staff;
}
```

So in the above code I'm trying to get the modules associated with the setter property, only it comes up with an exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO.getWithModules(StaffDAO.java:62)
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d033d033.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$710c2495.getWithModules(<generated>)
com.project.professional.service.StaffServiceImpl.getWithModules(StaffServiceImpl.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy102.getWithModules(Unknown Source)
com.project.professional.controller.StaffController.showStaffModules(StaffController.java:83)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Obviously the way I'm currently doing this is not completely right so what would be the best way for get each parent and their children?

Edit: highlighting the line 62 with the error:

```
   staff.setsModule(sModule);
```

Comment: Where is line 62 in StaffDAO?

Comment: It's this line - staff.setsModule(sModule); in the DAO class. The property sModule is the module property mapped by setter.

Comment: Then `staff` must be null, which means that `get(crit)` must be returning null. Dig into that to find out why.